# How do I keep programs in CentOS7?

Tags: linux, angular, background, gitbook

I am a beginner in using Linux.
I have run programs in the server through the Windows Terminal.

```
# gitbook build &
# ng serve &
```

But when I quit the terminal window, it ended with gitbook, anguler.
How can I keep it going?
I want to know the most common ways.

Comment: `nohup gitbook build &` or `gitbook build &; disown`? Also, see [How can I close a terminal without killing the command running in it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-close-a-terminal-without-killing-the-command-running-in-it).

Comment: The command is also terminated.
I'm sorry I did not do the question properly.
I have run programs in the server through the Windows Terminal. However, when I closed the terminal window, all the programs ended together. It looks like you are using a tool like forever, pm2 or registering with a service.

Comment: @birryree Thank you. I could solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run with `nohup`, it runs a command immune to hangups:

`nohup gitbook build > /dev/null`

or

`nohup gitbook build > /dev/null &`